# How to change the $.makeArray to zepto.js array

Tags: jquery, cordova, zepto

I am trying to migrate from jQuery to Zepto for my phonegap android app
Now I am getting this error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (t,e){return S.init(t,e)} has no method 'makeArray'
```

My script is

```
console.log($.makeArray(basket));
```

How do I change this to Zepto.js